# Angularjs won't read from an external json file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Hi I'm trying to get my angularJs site to read from an external JSON file located in js/data.json.  it only works if the json file is in the controller script...but when I remove it to data.json...it won't read it?  When I type in anything on the search bar...nothing comes up.  It only works when I include the script in the controller like:

```
personApp.controller('PersonListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/persons.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.persons = data;
    });
    $scope.persons = [{
        "name": "Mike Doe"
    }, {
        "name": "Jhon Doe"
    }, {
        "name": "Sam Doe"
    }, {
        "name": "Sam Doe"
    }, ]
});
```

I just want the two files to be separate for simplicity.  Thanks.

Is there an error in my controller code?

Thanks.

```
<body ng-app="personApp">
    <div class="container">
        <header></header>
        <div ng-controller="PersonListCtrl">
            <div class="bar">Search:
                <input ng-model="query">
            </div>
            <ul class="" ng-show="query">
                <li ng-repeat="person in persons | filter:query">{{person.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

script(really both module and controller are separate Js files.  I've included both for simplicity)

```
var personApp = angular.module('personApp', []);

personApp.controller('PersonListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.persons = data;
    });
});
```

and this is the external json file located in js/data.json

```
 [{
    "name": "Mike Doe"
}, {
    "name": "Jhon Doe"
}, {
    "name": "Sam Doe"
}, {
    "name": "Sam Doe"
}, ]
```

The JSON won't parse if I use:

```
personApp.controller('PersonListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/persons.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.persons = JSON.parse(data);
    });
});
```

and I keep getting an error on the browser console:  I think it's to do with the JSON PARSE in controller.

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at http://172.31.1.17/js/controllers/controllers.js:229:31
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js:80:486
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js:111:425
    at k.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js:125:305)
    at k.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js:122:398)
    at k.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js:126:58)
    at m (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js:81:275)
    at N (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js:85:364)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js:86:394)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are parsing it twice , the $http.get command already parses so no need to use JSON.parse(data); again

this should resolve your token O error

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to parse data before assigning it to $scope.persons

Change your controller code to

```
personApp.controller('PersonListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/persons.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.persons = JSON.parse(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I made the changes based on your recommendations but got an error in the console?

Says there's an error with:    $scope.persons = JSON.parse(data);
    });

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
        at Object.parse (native)
        at http://172.31.1.17/js/controllers/controllers.js:229:31

Comment: Just remove the extra semicolon in the array

Comment: I have removed the semi colon in the array.  Still getting errors.

Comment: Does console.log(data) returns a string or object?

Comment: No.  Just says " SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)"

Comment: The error is pointing to :   $scope.persons = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Do you have an idea why the error is pointing to your modification?  Thanks

Comment: its pointing to the data, as someone recommended, validate the JSON

Comment: The Json is validated!

I've used:    jsonlint.com and it says my json file is ok

Comment: and console.log(data) before the assignment, what does it give?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at http://172.31.1.17/js/controllers/controllers.js:233:31
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:80:385
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:112:20
    at l.$get.l.$eval

Answer (score 1):

> You have error in your json data.

```
[{
    "name": "Mike Doe"
}, {
    "name": "Jhon Doe"
}, {
    "name": "Sam Doe"
}, {
    "name": "Sam Doe"
}]; // <-- REMOVE SEMICOLON
```

Also parse JSON data using `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: Thanks, I've done the above but keep getting errors.

Comment: Thanks , that's a good site.  Seems that my JSON file is ok.  I think it's the controller that's causing the problems/